# Haptic Feedback vs. Force Feedback

Tags: meaning

> Is there a difference in *Haptic Feedback* and *Force Feedback*?

I use it in the context of a surface, e. g. a touch device, that vibrates or moves quickly if it is touched or pressed with a force that is larger than a specific force threshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haptics refers to the branch of engineering dealing with tactile human-machine interfaces.

Force feedback is a term that originates from control theory where force is used as input for the control system, rather than for instance position.

Haptic interfaces are often suitable for force feedback based control systems (because of compliance), which is why many haptic devices are controlled using force feedback. However, force feedback could also be applied in other fields, such as robotics.

If you want to refer to the control system behind the haptic interface specifically, then use force feedback. If you want to point out the fact that it is a haptic interface (i.e. tactile human-machine interaction), then use haptic feedback.

Comment: "where force is used as input" I believe you mean that force is the output (feedback) of the system.